# Opening a specific node in an asp.net tree view dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can any one help to expand a particular node according the value passed from a previous page..i.e:

Page1: Value to pass : hyp1

Page 2: Tree View-->  if (val == hyp1) then

SubNode in a node2 should open....

Can any one help me in doin this using C# in asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at expand method of TreeNode ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.expand.aspx

Comment: Thnk u for u answer Mr.Madhur...but I do know about the Expand and Collapse mtds but if I use it thn only parent node is expanding and sub nodes inside it are not expanding...I need to expand the particualt sub node of a parent node...tht thing I cant get using tht method...can help me now?